# Determining coordinates for CAD file using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, georeferencing, dxf, cad

I have a CAD file of a building and I want it to be replaced on Google Maps with coordinates.

The DXF-file is on a local coordinate system (undefined). I convert this file to SHP-file for editing. I have corner coordinates from Google Maps. I want to determine the WGS84 coordinates for this SHP-file.

Should i use the affine transformation method (what are the parameters?) or other method for ArcGIS?

Answer (score 2):

In ArcGIS you should load the CAD data first and use the Georeferencing toolbar to establish world file coordinates before converting to a shapefile as explained in the [Georeferencing CAD datasets](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/cad/georeferencing-cad-datasets.htm) help.  There are several related help links in this section that explain how you can apply a transformation, but that generally means that the local coordinates had to apply the rules of a known projection to choose the appropriate transformation.  In most cases a decent set of control points on a horizontal or vertical plane should be sufficient for placement and sizing of a single building footprint.